Weak coupling nonlinear solvers in PDE solvers
I have two time-dependent PDE solvers that target the nonlinear equations:
\begin{align}
\partial_t u - L_1(u) u &= f(v), \\
\partial_t v - L_2(v) v &= g(u),
\end{align}
where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are non-linear differential operators. See that the equation for the variable $u$ has a forcing term depending on $v$, and viceversa.
For any appropriate time-stepping scheme and space discretization scheme (FEM or FVM), I end up having to solve at each time step large nonlinear equations for the two PDEs, let's say find $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ such that $F_t(u(t),v(t)) = 0$ and $G_t(u(t), v(t)) = 0$, with $F_t$ and $G_t$ being possibly time-dependent functions.
For technical reasons (software) I cannot implement a strong coupling (solve for $u$ and $v$ together in a "monolithic" approach), but only a weak coupling. In particular, my approach consists now in (at each time step $t$)

Find $u(t)$ such that $F_t(u(t), v(t-1)) = 0$ with quasi-Newton iterations,
Find $v(t)$ such that $G_t(u(t),v(t))=0$ with quasi-Newton iterations.

I'm now thinking to couple more strongly by interweaving more the nonlinear iterations, meaning do one (or a few) Newton steps for $u$, then for $v$, then for $u$ until convergence.
What would be the benefits of such an approach?
What I think I might achieve:

Faster convergence of the nonlinear solvers (but I'm not sure I'd achieve this)
More accuracy
More stability

Is there any reference on these topics that I might look at?

Are you interested in the steady state or the evolution itself? In either case you could try a semi-implicit approach: \begin{align}
\frac{u^{k+1} -u^k}{\tau} - L_1(u^k)u^{k+1} &= f(v^k) \
\frac{v^{k+1}-v^k}{\tau} - L_2(v^k)v^{k+1} &= g(u^k)\end{align}
If $I-\tau L_1(u^k)$ and $I-\tau L_2(v^k)$ are positive definite you could use CG. For the steady state you can solve instead:
\begin{align}
L_1(u^k)u^{k+1} &= -f(v^k) \
L_2(v^k)v^{k+1} &= -g(u^k)\end{align}
Both are simpler than Newton since you don't need to compute the Jacobians. The term $L'_1(u^k)u^k$ was dropped from the Jacobian.

The above allows solving in parallel for $u$ and $v$. As an alternative you could solve for $u^{k+1}$ and plug it into $g(u^{k+1})$ and solve for $v^{k+1}$ with that updated right-hand side, or vice versa. You could also do multiple iterations on only one of the equations for every iteration of the other, if it is much more pathological. I don't know whether that is better for your problem - you can try whether there are any benefits. I really like this simpler fixed-point iteration for quasi-linear problems. You could try it before jumping to Newton.

@lightxbulb: On one side (let's say $v$) I'm using a PDE commercial solver, which uses some Newton-type nonlinear solver. What I can do is insert calls to user-defined functions where I run the other system (where I have more control) to obtain a "new" version of the forcing term (updated for $u$).

I guess the point is that you don't need the Newton-type nonlinear solver if the above works. You just need a linear solver and you have to decide how often you update $u$ compared to $v$. If the matrices $L_1(u^k), L_2(v^k)$ are symmetric negative semi-definite then conjugate gradients would do. If the matrices are symmetric but indefinite then SYMMLQ, conjugate residuals, minres. If the matrices are non-symmetric you could try Bi-CGStab.

I think that OP does not have access to any of the internal constructions for one of the PDEs; They have one PDE they have all access to and another that is essentially black box

@whpowell96: exactly. The best I can do is, at each time step, choose at when and how often I should solve for $u$ "while" I'm solving for $v$.

You could maybe still use some sort of Newton-Krylov method where you use exact Jacobians for one equation and a finite-difference Jacobian-vector product for the components in the other equation

How often you need to update one compared to the other (and how large the steps should be) depends on the problem. Although it is not the same, see for example: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377042722001960

A fully coupled is usually only needed if the coupling is stiff, that notion itself being less precise for coupled problems than for monolithic ODE problems. Do you have arguments that tend to show that the coupling is stiff (requirement of a very low step if the coupling is not iterated, unconditional instability...) ?
